# using cookies with supertest and jest

Tags: express, mongoose, cookies, jestjs, ts-jest

im making an api with express.js and mongoDB for an e-commerce website, and i have written a controller function that gets the cart of the user, the code for this function is :

```
const getCart = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { jwtToken } = req.signedCookies;
    const verified = jwt.verify(
      jwtToken,
      String(process.env.SECRET_KEY)
    ) as JwtPayload;
    const userCart = await Cart.find({ user: verified._id });
    res.status(200).json(userCart);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json(err);
  }
};
```

the jwt token is set in a signed httpOnly cookie after a user logs in, and it has several fields related to the user, but im only using the user id here.

now when i want to test the getCart() method with jest, i have written the following code (not exactly the same, some things are not included because they are not important):

```
// assume request and app are already imported
describe('GET /cart', () => {
  
 it('should return user cart when authenticated', async () => {
    
    const response = await request.(app)
      .get('/api/cart')
      .set('Cookie', [`jwtToken=${sampleToken}`]);
      console.log(res.headers["set-cookie"]); // just to check if there was a cookie set
    })
  })
```

but it seems like theres no cookie being set at all, the output of the console.log in the test is undefined, how am i supposed to send a cookie for the test to pass?